# Bugzilla's Activate / Deactivate Task

Tags: eclipse, task, tracking, bugzilla, mylyn

I am using Eclipse and when I create bugs there is a button on the top next to the number [O Bug XX]. When I click on the "O" area it activates the task. It seems like only one task can be active at a time. I am assuming that when a task is active, it is showing others working within your project that this is what you are working on? Looking for an in depth explanation on this feature, please.

I looked through the documentation and didn't see anything about it except the shortcut keys to activate / deactivate it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Activating a task is a core function of Mylyns' `task-focused UI`.

As best described in Mylyn's FAQ:

> When you activate a task, Mylyn automatically maintains a task context
>   by monitoring your interaction. The task context provides a
>   predictable degree-of-interest weighting of the relevance of the
>   elements and relations that you work with to the task-at-hand (as
>   described in the [Foundations of Software Engineering conference
>   paper](http://kerstens.org/mik/publications/2006-11-mylar-fse.pdf)). The Task-Focused UI is the mechanism by which Mylyn presents
>   Mylyn the task-context model in order to reduce information overload
>   and to automate the manual management of UI elements like editors and
>   change sets. Examples:
>
> - Filtering, decoration and expansion management in views
> - Automatic folding in editors
> - Ranking in content assist
> - Editor management
> - Perspective management
> - Change set management

To learn how to use Mylyn's context management in your development workflow, i recommend reading the IBM article [Mylyn 2.0, Part 2: Automated context management](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-mylyn2/).